# Count/sum occurrences of word in cell in column - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

I have two columns of text/abbreviations i want to summarize in a (or two respectively) tables.

Example:

Column 1: SiteScopeInput

> Swap_G09+Remove_U21+Rollout_L07+Swap_L08+Swap_L18+Rollout_L21+Rollout_N35
> Remove_U21+Rollout_L07+Swap_L08+Swap_L18+Rollout_L21+Rollout_N35
> Swap_G09+Rollout_L07+Swap_L08+Swap_L09+Swap_L18+Rollout_L21+Swap_L26+Rollout_N35
> Swap_G09+Remove_U21+Rollout_L07+Swap_L08+Swap_L18+Rollout_L21+Rollout_N35

Here I'd like to summarize how many times words occure - for example:
Swap_G09
Remove_U1
Rollout_L07
and so on.

I've tried a combination of
`ArrayFormula, LEN and REGEXREPLACE`
but my beginner mind can't wrap around this task.

Any tips? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to treat Swap_G09 etc. as a separate word, then a combination of split, flatten and query should do it:

```
=ArrayFormula(query(FLATTEN(split(filter(A:A,A:A<>""),"+")),"select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label Col1 'Word'"))
```

[image]

Comment: You're welcome! Plz accept the answer by clicking on the tick if it's useful and you will get some rep points.

Comment: Accepted as solution. Unfortunately I haven't got enough reputation to cast a wote, tho I'd surely give you one.